# Heroku Scheduler and PHP

Tags: php, heroku, scheduler

I have seen many instructions using Heroku Scheduler , but none explain how to use PHP with it. Would anyone have a good example of PHP being used with the Heroku Scheduler? I don't want to be pointed to something that isn't with PHP, since all the replies i saw to similar questions did not show how to properly setup the Heroku Scheduler to work with PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Create a job in scheduler and add this to the task section:

```
php ~/www/[path to php file in your repo]
```

So if cron.php is at the root of your repository, it would look like this:

```
php ~/www/cron.php
```

Please note: this assumes that Heroku already "knows" that this is a php app.

(Heroku has released new php support, so I've updated this answer.)

Note: Change "www" to whatever your app's "webroot" is. If "webroot" is same as "approot" then just use "~/"

Comment: It's actually `php ~/www/cron.php` `~/bin/php` no longer exists.

Comment: Correct. You'll notice this was added before the new composer-friendly PHP support came out.

Comment: but everytime you push your app would the cron jobs be deleted at all?